# Donors who gave the same amount in X and Y year

Tags: civireport

Is there a report in the Current version of CiviCRM that can tell us this? https://civicrm.org/extensions/advanced-fundraising-reports seems to have reports that will show if the giving is increased or decreased year to year, but not if it's exactly the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is such a report. I would probably look at using [Summary Fields extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields) and then adding a new calculated field that does your calculation - and then report on that.

In drupal I would also consider doing this in Views and using eg views_calc to do the calculation for me instead of creating a calculated field

Comment: I will need to compare 16-17, and 17-18 (etc.) going into the future. It seems like a view offers more flexibility. The other reporting requirement is to ask if they gave the same for X and Y year, but then increased or decreased in Z year.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to try petednz's approach using Views Calc, but I hacked together a quick MySQL query that pulled me most of what I wanted

```
select year(receive_date) as year,(select display_name from civicrm_contact where civicrm_contribution.contact_id = civicrm_contact.id) as Name, contact_id, SUM(total_amount) as Gifts
from civicrm_contribution 
where (receive_date >= '2015-11-01' and receive_date <='2016-11-01') or (receive_date >= '2016-11-02' and receive_date >= '2017-11-01') or (receive_date >= '2017-11-01' and receive_date >= '2018-11-02')
group by contact_id, year, financial_type_id
having financial_type_id in (11, 12, 15, 25, 26)
ORDER BY name
```

Perhaps it can help someone else